# problem with powerdot

Tags: compiling, powerdot

After updating some packages of MiKTeX 2.9 (automatic update), it's impossible to obtain a ps file following the root : tex-> dvi->ps. ghostview fails to display the file.

Here below a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{psfrag}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{D1}
bla bla bla
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you get any error during the compilation? The `.ps` file shows correctly for me (Windows + GSView)

Comment: For reference, Azzam wrote to the mailing list here: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2013/010173.html also note that I reported a PSTricks regression a few days earlier here: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2013/010169.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution, as suggested in [this thread](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2013/010184.html) (by the maintainer of PS Tricks) is to load the pst-ovl package:

```
\usepackage{pst-ovl}
```